# ¿Cuál es la función de estos operadores en C#?

Tags: c#, operador

Hace unos días, encontré estas expresiones en C#:

```
string value     = default!                // con el operador NOT lógico !
void SomeMethod(object arg!!)              // con el operador !!
obj1             ??= obj2                  // con el operador ??=
object? myObject = null                    // con el operador ?
string text      = someString ?? ""        // con el operador ??
string name      = obj?.Name  ?? ""        // con el operador ?.
global::System.Console.WriteLine("Hello")  // con el operador ::
```

Y me siento algo confuso respecto a ellos debido a que soy nuevo en este lenguaje de programación.

¿Podría alguien ayudarme a entender estos operadores?

Comment: Recuerdo haber leído en alguna parte que el operador `!` (null forgiving) debería evitarse ya que suprime las advertencias e impide encontrar algunos potenciales problemas. Solo debería usarse cuando estás seguro de que el valor no es null.

Comment: @Mateo Muchas gracias por la información. Este operador parecer guardar cierto parecido con el uso de las directivas `#pragma warning disable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Permíteme decirte que C# ofrece una amplia gama de operadores, de los cuales algunos podrían parecer confusos para alguien que está empezando en el lenguaje, pero créeme que no es tan complejo como parece.

---

El operador `!` que en este caso no es un NOT lógico sino que más bien se trata del [operador Permite valores NULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving)

Este operador se usa para suprimir las advertencias de nulidad del compilador, y que sería algo así como decirle: *Esto no es nulo, te lo aseguro* y se aplica a los tipos que aceptan valores `null` ya sean tipos de referencia (clases) o tipos de valor (estructuras) anulables.

Por ejemplo:

```
string value = null;      // Lanza una alerta de posible valor nulo
string value = default;   // Lanza una alerta de posible valor nulo
string value = null!;     // Suprime la alerta de posible valor nulo
string value = default!;  // Suprime la alerta de posible valor nulo
```

---

El operador `!!` es el de "validación de argumentos null" y haciendo honor a su nombre, se usa para simplificar expresiones como estas:

```
ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(argument)

// Que a su vez equivale a
if (argument == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(argument));
}
```

Se usa frente al nombre de los argumentos de una función:

```
void MyFunction(object argument1!!, string argument2!!)
```

Aunque es preciso mencionar que parece que Microsoft [removió este operador](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp-11-preview-updates/#remove-parameter-null-checking-from-c-11)

---

Los operadores `??` y `??=` son los [operadores de fusión null](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

`??` devuelve el valor del operando izquierdo si no es `null` y en caso contrario devuelve el valor del operando derecho.

Por ejemplo:

```
string source1 = "Hello";
string source2 = null;

string dest1   = source1 ?? "NULL"; // dest1 será "Hello" porque source1 no es null
string dest2   = source2 ?? "NULL"; // dest2 será "NULL" porque source2 es null
```

`??=` en cambio, asigna el valor de su operando derecho a su operando izquierdo solo si el operando izquierdo es `null`.

Por ejemplo:

```
string dest1   = null;
string dest2   = "World";

dest1          ??= "Hello"; // dest1 es null, entonces se le asigna el valor "Hello"
dest2          ??= "Hello"; // dest2 no es null, por lo que conserva su valor "World"
```

---

El operador `?` es azúcar sintáctico para la [estructura Nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-7.0) y permite especificar que un tipo acepta valores `null`.

Verás, en C# existen los tipos de referencia (clases) que admiten valores `null`.

Por ejemplo:

```
class MyClass {}

MyClass myClass  = null; // Permitido
object  myObject = null; // Permitido
```

Y los tipos de valor (estructuras) que no admiten valores `null`.

Por ejemplo:

```
struct MyStruct {}

MyStruct myStruct = null; // No permitido
int      myInt    = null; // No permitido
```

Que los tipos de valor no admitan valores `null` no significa que no exista una manera de asignarles dicho valor, eso es lo que hace precisamente la estructura `Nullable<T>`.

Por ejemplo:

```
Nullable<int> myNullableInt = null; // Permitido
int?          myNullableInt = null; // Permitido y equivale a Nullable<int>
```

En C# también existen los [tipos de referencia que aceptan valores null](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types) que permiten marcar un objeto como un posible contenedor de un valor `null`.

Anteriormente vimos el operador `!` Permite valores `null` que suprime las advertencias de posible nulidad. Dicha advertencia también se suprime si marcas un tipo como anulable.

Por ejemplo:

```
string  str1 = null;  // Advertencia de nulidad
string  str2 = null!; // Suprime la advertencia de nulidad
string? str3 = null;  // Suprime la advertencia de nulidad
string? str4 = null!; // Suprime la advertencia de nulidad
```

---

El operador `?.` es conocido como el [operador condicional NULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

Si tienes algo como esto:

```
string result = myClass.Property1.Property2.Property3.ToString();
```

Y uno de estos (`myClass`, `Property1`, `Property2` o `Property3`) es `null` entonces una `NullReferenceException` será lanzada rompiendo todo el proceso.

Uno resolvería esto con algunas validaciones:

```
string result = "N/A";

if (myClass           != null &&
    myClass.Property1 != null &&
    myClass.Property2 != null &&
    myClass.Property3 != null)
{
    result = myClass.Property1.Property2.Property3.ToString();
}
```

Pero qué tedioso resulta todo esto. El operador `?.` resuelve esto simplificando el bloque anterior a una simple línea:

```
string result = myClass?.Property1?.Property2?.Property3?.ToString() ?? "N/A";
```

---

El operador `::` es el [operador de alias del espacio de nombres](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/namespace-alias-qualifier) y permite acceder a un miembro de espacio de nombres con alias, un alias `extern` o un alias `global`.

Por ejemplo:

```
using system = System;

system::Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
```